# Java Best Practices - Returning an Object vs. a Generic

Tags: java, object, generics, junit

I'm using Generics for the first time for a school project and I have come across a philosophical dilemma regarding whether to return objects or my declared generic element in my methods.

My OCD is telling me that I need to always return the known type but I'm finding that doing so creates some downstream annoyances when I feed primitive datatypes into my class (and, of course, for this project I'm only ever feeding primitives into this class).

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public class DansPriorityQueue<E extends Comparable> 
{
    private ArrayList<E> tree;

//Here's a method that returns an object
public Object peek() {
    return tree.get(0);
}

//Here's a method that returns the generic type
public E peek() {
    return tree.get(0);
}
```

(As an FYI.. I'm required to implement this JDK class myself but I am *fortunately* not required to implement the same interfaces that the real PriorityQueue does so I do have a choice as to whether I want to use the Object or the generic)

**My Issue**

It makes me feel a little dirty but I'm tempted just to return an Object rather than my E generic element on these methods because when I return E, JUnit forces me to cast my integer values:

```
DansPriorityQueue<Integer> dpq = new DansPriorityQueue<Integer>();
dpq.add(1);
assertEquals("Expected different value", (Integer) 1, dpq.peek());
```

When I return an object on the other hand, the auto-boxing doesn't force me cast my primitive value.

Here's a more eloquent description of the issue I've been facing:

http://www.aschroder.com/2009/10/php-1-java-0-the-method-assertequalsobject-object-is-ambiguous-for-the-type/

**------------EDIT----------------**

Here's the actual error I receive when I return the generic type and fill my list with the autoboxed Integer object without the cast above: The method assertEquals(String, Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type DansPriorityQueueTest

**--------- END EDIT--------------**

**Questions**

1. Can anyone tell me why I should or should not return an object as opposed to the generic element I'm working with? Both seem to have upsides and downsides... what's the best practice?
2. I know vaguely that returning an Object can cause some casting issues later on but I've not yet run into them... does anyone have a specific example of how this can be dangerous?
3. In the JDK, I've noticed that many of the Collections methods return Object by default. Is this because Generics was introduced in a later version of Java or was this a conscious decision by Sun Systems?

Comment: Can you not just parametrize the generic with Integer and it all works for you with the magic of autoboxing?

Comment: What does `dpq.size()` declare as its return type?  I'm a little bit confused because your example uses a call that doesn't seem to use `peek()` at all, so not sure I understand the relevance.  `size()` isn't a method that would be generic on a collection's element type.

Comment: Sorry about that I edited it with the peek method above... I had grabbed the wrong test.

Comment: @InfernalRapture - Can you explain what you mean? From my understanding you have to pass primitives through their Auto-boxed partners so when I declare this class I say DansPriorityQueue<Integer>. Is that what you mean by parametrize?

Comment: @DanK I'm failing to understand your issue here.  Returning an Object will obligate EVERYBODY to cast your return type which is a righteous pain in the bum.  Generics allow for compile-time checking of types which provides type-safety you'd have to handle in-code otherwise.  If you're asking about how to handle your JUnit test, there's generally no standard.  Test code is allowed to deviate from best practices if it makes life easier, it's the production code that shouldn't.

Comment: Re JUnit.  There are several overloaded versions of `assertEquals()` - for example: `assertEquals(Object, Object)` and `assertEquals(int, int)`.  The need to cast often crops up when auto-boxing makes which one you mean ambiguous, for example: `assertEquals(42, new Integer(42))`.  Should the compiler box the first here or unbox the second?  (Keeping in mind that the compiler doesn't know that, actually, it doesn't matter.  I resolve this by having all my unit tests extend my own `BaseTest extends TestCase` class, with an `assertInteger(int exp, int act) { assertEquals(exp, act); }`.

Comment: @Paul - That's actually the best explanation for that error I've seen. Thank you... seriously! That's great advice.

Comment: Re 'Re Junit'.  I also add a whole bunch of other useful assert methods - `assertSize(col)`, `assertNoNulls(col)`, `assertException(e, msg)`, `assertToString(obj, s)`, etc.

Comment: BTW.  Shouldn't `DansPriorityQueue<E extends Comparable>` be `DansPriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>>`?  Should probably make `tree` final too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why I should or should not return an object as opposed to the generic element I'm working with? Both seem to have upsides and downsides... what's the best practice?

It depends. In a case like this you'd want to generic type - otherwise what's the point of defining generic type for the class?

> I know vaguely that returning an Object can cause some casting issues later on but I've not yet run into them... does anyone have a specific example of how this can be dangerous?

Sure!

```or-tag-here
DansPriorityQueue<String> queue = new DansPriorityQueue<String>();
//add items
Float f = (Float)queue.getObject();  //uh-oh! this compiles but will fail 
Float f = queue.getObject(); //generic type, fails during compile
```

> In the JDK, I've noticed that many of the Collections methods return Object by default. Is this because Generics was introduced in a later version of Java or was this a conscious decision by Sun Systems?

It's due to backward compatibility mostly, or for cases where you truly will use the collection to contain disparate values (a mishmash of say, JLabels, Strings and Icons for instance for rendering a JTable for instance).

> assertEquals("Expected different size", (Integer) 2, dpq.size());

I don't think this should be a problem. dpq.size() should just return an int regardless off what is stored in the priority queue. It would not be a generic value.

You can create something like

```or-tag-here
DansPriorityQueue<Double> queue = new DansPriorityQueue<Double>();
for(double d = 0; d < 10; d+=1.0)
    queue.add(d);
```

and that should cause no issues, right?

Comment: Thanks Markus.. this is very helpful. I listed the wrong test method before though. When I do a peek on an auto-boxed Integer and I'm returning the explicit generic type, I'm getting the following error unless I cast it: The method assertEquals(String, Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type DansPriorityQueueTest

Comment: Of course it's ambiguous if you have both return types available. However, if you remove the public Object peek() -method, there will be no ambiguity left.

Comment: :-) I have two peeks methods for illustration only. In my project there is only one peek method. The ambiguity is because I'm listing an int value in my test but my class is returning an Integer object. For some reason, it's unable to reconcile the two. See the link above for more detail.

Comment: Okay, well if you want the result to look prettier you can do this:   int value = dpq.peek(); assertEquals("Expected different value",  1,  value);  and that should resolve the issue. This is one of the corner cases of auto-unboxing you've bumped into.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense... Thanks Markus!